# glmnet beaviour with non-unique solutions

Tags: r, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm using R package *glmnet* to fit a lasso logit model (alpha=1) on a binary response with about binary 60'000 predictors.

By the results in http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/lassounique.pdf, the solution shouldn't be unique, however, both estimation via *glmnet* and *cv.glmnet* end well, with no problem.

So I'm wondering how does *glmnet* behave with non-unique solutions. Does it compute one of the infinite linear predictors (as it is unique even with non-unique solutions) and return it as a solution?